# How to replace fusion drive and restore MacOS?

Tags: fusion-drive

I have 2014 Mac Mini with fusion drive running Catalina. If I replace original fusion SSD with bigger one, can I restore Time Machine backup or reinstall OS?

Comment: why would you suspect that you couldn't...

Comment: If you're going to replace the original SSD with a new SSD of sufficient capacity, then don't make it a Fusion drive: just use it as an SSD. Fusion drives are a compromise between speed and space: if you're increasing the SSD space, you don't need to cripple the speed by fusing it to an Hdd.

Comment: thanks for tips...so can I just restore by backup from Time Machine?

Answer (score 0):

you should go to ifixit site and look to see if they talk about replacing the drive. There are several ifixit sites devototed to the Mac Mini. One site is [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Mac_Mini_Late_2014).